# setting the correct jpa mapping for shopping cart items and product

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, relation

I am learning jpa through some examples ,involving a shopping cart and cart items.I defined them as below..but am not very sure about which mapping to use

```
@Entity
class Product{

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   ...
}

@Entity
class CartItem{
   private Long id;

   private Product product;

   private int quantity;

...
}

@Entity
class ShoppingCart{
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany
   private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

  ...
}
```

What I am not very sure of ,is how to relate between `Product and CartItem` and how to set the `mappedBy` attribute.Can somebody tell me how to do this?What are the criteria in doing this?I was trying to set something like `1 cartitem contains 1 product only`.It sounds like a `OneToOne` relation.If so, who maintains the relation(is that not what `mappedBy` does?).I have similar doubt about `ShoppingCart` and `CartItem`s too

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One cart item references one product. But a single product is referenced by several cart items. So it's a one-to-many association.

One shopping cart as several items, and an item is part of one shopping cart, so it's also a one-to-many association.

When you have a bidirectional OneToMany association, the owner side of the association is always the *many* side. The owner side of an association is the side where there is no `mappedBy` attribute. Indeed, `mappedBy` means "*I'm just the other side of an association, which is already mapped by the following attribute*". Note that the way the asociation is mapped (join column, join table) must only be defined on the owner side, where the `mappedBy` attribute is absent.

When you have a unidirectional association, there is only one place where the mapping can be defined, and the mappedBy attribute is thus never used.

So, your entities should be mapped like this:

```
@Entity
class Product{

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   ...
}

@Entity
class CartItem{
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   private Product product;

   private int quantity;

...
}

@Entity
class ShoppingCart{
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany
   private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

  ...
}
```

If you want your cart item to know about its owning shopping cart, your association becomes bidirectional, and the entities become:

```
@Entity
class CartItem{
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   private Product product;

   @ManyToOne
   private ShppingCart shoppingCart;

   private int quantity;

...
}

@Entity
class ShoppingCart{
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shoppingCart")
   private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I have a couple of (noobish)doubts.In the cart,I do not want to allow two CartItems that refer to the same Product.If user want to buy more number of same Product,he can increment the quantity.So,is it right to give a ManyToOne between CartItem and Product?

Comment: Yes. ManyToOne means "there are many cart items for the same product". The fact that there can't be several items *in the same shopping cart* for the same product is irrelevant here. You should check this constraint in the Java code, and set a unique constraint on [shopping_cart_id, product_id] in the table of the cart items.

Comment: "there are many cart items for the same product" - Does that make sense given that there is a quantity field available?  A OneToOne relationship with a quantity field seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: @AlanSmith that would be true if there was only one shopping cart. But a shop which would only have one shopping cart would quickly go out of business. Each shopping cart has many cart items, and it's thus normal for several cart items to reference the same product (because they're simply part of distinct shopping carts).

Comment: @JB ok I get you now.  It's across carts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You ought to first decide whether you want a unidirectional or a bidirectional `@OneToOne` relationship. A unidirectional relationship has an owning side (the side where the reference to another class is present), while a bidirectional relationship has both an owning side and an inverse side.

If you are declaring a unidirectional `@OneToOne` relationship, then you do not need to worry about the `mappedBy` attribute. For example, if you declare the `Product`-`CartItem` relationship as a unidirectional relationship with the `CartItem` owning the relationship (and also possessing the foreign key in the database), then you merely need to annotate a reference to the `Product` in the `Product` class, as shown below; no changes are required in the `Product` class:

```
@Entity
class CartItem{
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne
   private Product product;

   private int quantity;

...
}
```

If you need a bi-directional relationship, then you must define references that go both ways. In this case, you'll need to add a reference to a `CartItem` from the `Product` class. Furthermore, you'll need to specify the `mappedBy` attribute on the inverse side, to refer to the owning side (the side that has the foreign key in the database), as shown below:

```
@Entity
class Product{

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="product") // the name of the property in the owning side
   private CartItem cartItem;
   ...
}

@Entity
class CartItem{
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne                    //the owning side
   private Product product;

   private int quantity;

...
}
```

Comment: is it OneToOne between   CartItem and Product? JB Nizet opinioned that it should be ManyToOne

Comment: Well, that depends on how you want to model the relationship; a `ManyToOne` would imply that a single `Product` can be referenced from multiple `CartItem`s (which appears to make sense), while a `OneToOne` would imply that a `Product` can be referenced from only one `CartItem` *at an instant*. Also, `@ManyToOne` happens to be the inverse of a `@OneToMany` relationship, so it's usually easier to think of a `OneToMany` to verify if the inverse is a `ManyToOne` relationship. Finally, you'll need to specify either annotation for a unidirectional relationship, and both for a bidirectional one.